# Seems to conflict between Serverless syntax and CloudFormation syntax

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

The below is the part of CloudForamtion file loaded by Serverless.

```
# resource.yml
.
.
.
{"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:sqs:*:${AWS::AccountId}:sqs-spoon-*-${env:SERVICE}"}

# serverless.yml
.
.
resources:
  - ${file:resource.yml}
```

`${AWS::AccountId}` is CloudFormation Pseudo Parameter and `${env:SERVICE}` is Serverless variable.

When I run `sls deploy`, it returns the error.

```
  Invalid variable reference syntax for variable AWS::AccountId. You can only reference env vars, options, & files. You can check our docs for more info.
```

It seems to say that Serverless recognize `${AWS::AccountId}` as Serverless variable, not as CloudFormation Pseudo Parameter.

Right?

If so, how to have Serverless not to parse Pseudo Parameter so that it will be parsed by CloudFormation later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve it with the [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-pseudo-parameters).

With the plugin, It cloud be solved by replacing `${AWS::AccountId}` with `#{AWS::AccountId}`.

```
{"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:sqs:*:#{AWS::AccountId}:sqs-spoon-*-${env:SERVICE}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish support for the native AWS syntax with a single config line in `serverless.yml` to define the `variableSyntax`. Details can be found here https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/3694.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  variableSyntax: "\${((env|self|opt|file|cf|s3)[:\(][ :a-zA-Z0-9._,\-\/\(\)]*?)}"
```